# Right side of UIWebView cut off despite constraints

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS application with an UIWebView object. I've put in constraints so that the app would display correctly across all iOS devices. The constraints work correctly for the most part. However, the right side of the UIWebView object is cut off even though there is supposed to be 15 pixels between it and the edge of the superview. I've set the spacing to an absurdly high value (like 250 pixels), but it doesn't help.

Any advice?

[image: UiWebView as it appears in Xcode]

Comment: upload an image of your XIB where constraints are visible. If you are using visual format, publish the code or publish anyway your code as more as possible.

Comment: I've added a picture. I can post relevant parts of the source code if needed.

Comment: you have all your constraints in warning. Please update it by clicking the button bottom right and clicking update constraints